# Record a video with time lapse on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I have tried to record a video with Google Glass and Android SDK setting quality to `QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW` but not frames were recorded. I have tried also with `QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_HIGH` and setting the VideoEncoder codec to `MPEG_4_SP`instead of the default `H264`.

The time lapse record worked on a Nexus 10 (Android 4.3)

Here is the relevant part of my code, where I set the recorded video profile:

```
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW);
profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP; //I have tried also with the default: H264
_mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(2.0); //I have tried also with 10.0 fps
_mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
```

Comment: When comparing what works on other devices, remember that Glass is still running Android 4.0.3

Comment: @rymo QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW was added on API Level 11. I haven't other 4.0.3 device to test

Comment: Have you found a solution or a workaround?